# code not able to distinguish wrong from no response

Tags: python, response, psychopy

I have an experiment where possible response to provide are:

1. correct
2. not correct
3. no response

Unfortunately with the code as follows I am not able to distiguish wrong from no response:

```
if (trial_resp.keys == str(corrAns)) or (trial_resp.keys == corrAns):
 trial_resp.corr = 1

elif (trial_resp.keys == []) or (trial_resp.keys == []): 
 trial_resp.corr = 'none' 

else: 
 trial_resp.corr =  0
```

What would you recommend

Comment: Why do you not change your code so that you can distinguish wrong from no response? I would recommend that.

Comment: Could you please recommend some way?

Comment: I'm unable, I don't know how your code works.

Comment: What does `(trial_resp.keys == []) or (trial_resp.keys == [])` mean? Why is `trial_resp.keys == []` repeated?

Comment: You are right. The repetition was a distraction on my side. Actually I have put the code like that to state any different response from the two keyboard designed to be used from right and wrong response